# what does double star regex means in spring security url

Tags: spring, spring-security

i recently came across a spring project where i saw a security configuration like following

```
<intercept-url pattern="/register/**" access="permitAll()" />
```

After google and digging more i was not able to find out what the double star means `/register/**`  It would be great if anybody could explain me. What is the significance of stars in urls spring security.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These patters are Ant-style path patterns (https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns). The ** matches zero or more 'directories' in a path, take a look at [AntPathMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)